# Is there a way to go from a Microsoft Word document to a Google-sites wiki?

Tags: wiki, google-sites

I've a Microsoft Word report that I would like to be able to do a quick and dirty demo of how it would look and feel as an online wiki. Is there a way to do this with the wiki in Google-sites? I assume I have to make the Word doc a Google doc first, but is there a way to then convert that to a set of wiki pages automatically or semi-automatically, with headings defining separate wiki pages?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] There is no built-in way in the new Google Sites to do that, AFAIK, Google isn't offering a way to automate the new Google Sites (there is no API and Google Apps Script sites service doesn't work with new Google Sites) and as the classic Google Sites was deprecated your automation option might be to use web-browser automation tool. If you would like a suggestion about what web-browser automation tool to use, checkout [sofwarerecs.se] specially there "How to ask" guidelines.

Comment: If you need further help here. please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]